I want to draw plot by matplotlib
I want to have plot by matplotlib to show the temperature change along time in lat. I got this: WARNING: x coordinate not montonically increasing - contour plot may not be what you expect. If it looks odd, you can either adjust the map projection region to be consistent with your data, or (if your data is on a global lat/lon grid) use the shiftgrid function to adjust the data to be consistent with the map projection region (see examples/contour_demo.py)
d=Dataset('sst.mon.ltm.1991-2020.nc')

sst=d.variables['sst']

time=d.variables['time']

lon=d.variables['lon'][:]

lat=d.variables['lat'][:]

mean_sst=np.mean(sst,axis=(2),keepdims=False)

ax=fig-subplots(121)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax=fig.add_subplot(211)
m = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlon= 0,urcrnrlon=180,llcrnrlat=-80,urcrnrlat=0)
lat_grid,time_grid=np.meshgrid(lat,time)

cx=m.contourf(lat_grid,time_grid,mean_sst,cmap='seismic')

plt.show()


Please change the title of the post to something more specific.

The warning is trying to tell you that the longitudes are outside the -180/180 range :
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 lon(lon)
    units: degrees_east
    long_name: Longitude
    actual_range: [  0. 358.] # <<< here
    standard_name: longitude
    axis: X
    coordinate_defines: center
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (180,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used

So, as suggested, you can use a shiftgrid so they suit the Mercator projection :
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import shiftgrid

sst, lon = shiftgrid(180.0, sst, lon, start=False, cyclic=lon.max())

NB: Your meshgrid is not contructed properly and must include the longitudes as well.
Animation (see full code) using this dataset :

